# MySQL Search a ROW for ALL COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am working on a Job and I have come across a hurdle. I am working with MySQL to create a procedure which would match data from a column `A_col_1` of a table `tbl_A` to `B_col1` till `B_col12`of table `tbl_B`. The query should then return the data matched and two more columns. This has to be done for `A_col_1` till `A_col_12`

This is to be done in a Stored Procedure (Client's Request). Can anyone point me in the right direction? My brain seems to have stopped working. :)

Table Structure of the DB:

- Table A is `tbl_play_ns`
- Table B is `tbl_draw`

[image: ERD of the original DB]

Comment: Let us say, if in a row in A, if `A.n1` does not match with any of `B.n1` through `B.n12` values but `A.n3` matches. Then how do you want to pick the row?

Comment: Are you expecting something like `... where A.n1 in (B.n1, ..., B.n12 ) AND A.n2 in (B.n1, ..., B.n12) ...`?

Comment: @Ravinder Yes, Kind of.

Comment: 1.NORMALIZE your design

Comment: If `tbl_play_ns`'s all n rows does not match a column in a row, then I dont want that row data.

Comment: Isn't it already normalized? Open to suggestions.